# How can I split a date and time into an array in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code that splits dd/mm/yy :

```
var ukDatea = a.split('/');
return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
```

How can I change this so that I can use dd/mm/yy hh:MM and then get the hours and minutes into another array called ukTime? My problem is I am not sure how to split the remainder of the time?

Comment: the variable a it's a datetime?

Comment: Why not use DateTime structure?

Comment: Why not parse it into a `DateTime` and break it out from there?

Comment: You should really consider to use a `DateTimes` for `Date` and `Times` not strings or arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing that:

- First split on the space, then split the date part on slash and the time part on colon.
- Use a regular expression to extract all the parts.
- Use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method to parse the string into a `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 1):

First split with `var arr = a.Split(" ")`. You have now dd/mm/yy and hh:MM in a array. 
Now use `arr[0].Split('/')` to get dd mm and yy. 
For time use `arr[1].Split(':')` and you get hh and MM

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.datetime.aspx) structure is what you're looking for.

From your original `a` string containing your date, you can create a DateTime structure with:

```
DateTime MyDateTime;
dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(a, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",
                              null);
```

MyDateTime then contains a date structure.
You can then define ukDatea:

```
string[] ukDatea = new string[3] { dateTime.Day, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Year };
```

and

```
string[] ukTime - new string[2] { dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute };
```