# Get time from excel and format data to array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a score system for athletics using records from an excel sheet.
I succeeded in the 100m and 200m where the time records are in seconds (example: 10,42)
(I loaded the records of the columns in an array (double[])).

The problem I am experiencing now is that the longest distances have also minutes in the format: "1:48,12".
How can I populate an array with such records format and compare the values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can custom format cells in Excel like this
then enter a time like 
0:01:10.99 
(zero hours, one minute, ten point nine nine seconds)

You can then perform calculations with these values. 
I don't know anything about how points are allocated in athletics so cannot advise on that.

Comment: He could make all those calculations in excel. Thats clear. The question is how to store in array the format with minutes and use the same for calculations. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143393/how-can-i-split-a-date-and-time-into-an-array-in-c